How do I depend on prebuilt Node.js binaries of better-sqlite3, instead of building them myself?
I have an old TypeScript/Node.js component which uses better-sqlite3 version 7.6.1 with the help of PNPM.
I want to lift the Node version (and other dependencies too).
When I build my component, it also wants to build better-sqlite3. This fails for me, both on Windows and on Linux,
The better-sqlite3 site says there are pre-built binaries.
(Because I use TypeScript, I also want to use @types/better-sqlite3 which seems to only be available for better-sqlite3 version 7. Otherwise I would consider lifting to version 9.)
How do I force PNPM to use these pre-built binaries?
How can I tell which versions of better-sqlite3 packages actually contain pre-built binaries?
I do get this line:
prebuild-install warn install No prebuilt binaries found (target=21.7.3 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=linux)
Is it automatic, and unable to find it?
